# dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of shim-signed

Tags: grub-efi

Getting the following errors after upgrading. The configuration of shim-signed didn't go through due to dependency problems.

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
    grub-efi-amd64-signed
    shim-signed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling grub-efi and updating grub fixes the issue.

```
sudo apt-get purge grub\*
sudo apt-get install grub-efi
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo update-grub
```